# Exception: The speech privacy policy was not accepted prior to attempting a speech recognition

Tags: c#, exception, uwp, speech-recognition, iot

From where do I have to accept the speech recognition policy?

Here is the code

```
public async void display()
{
    SpeechRecognizer rec = new SpeechRecognizer();
    await rec.CompileConstraintsAsync();
    rec.Timeouts.InitialSilenceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    rec.Timeouts.EndSilenceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
    rec.UIOptions.AudiblePrompt = "I am listening";
    rec.UIOptions.ShowConfirmation = true;
    rec.UIOptions.IsReadBackEnabled = true;
    rec.Timeouts.BabbleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    SpeechRecognitionResult result = await rec.RecognizeAsync(); // Error here

    if (result!=null)
    {
        textBlock.Text= result.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: In addition to HappyPig's answer, you might need to address this error too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45008609/uwp-speech-recognition

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is a setting under Speech, Inking and Typing. 
First, go to Settings and click "Time & Language". [image: Settings app]
Next, select "Speech" from the menu on the left.[image: Select from the menu]
After that, press "Speech, inking & typing privacy settings".[image: Go to the real setting]
Just press the button called "Get to know me".
[image: The setting]
Then, click the popup to turn the setting on.
[image: One more step]
After that, any software that uses the Speech Recognition API will work.

A helpful way to tell users to turn on would be...

```
catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException e) when (e.HResult == unchecked((int)0x80045509))
//privacyPolicyHResult
//The speech privacy policy was not accepted prior to attempting a speech recognition.
{
    ContentDialog Dialog = new ContentDialog()
    {
        Title = "The speech privacy policy was not accepted",
        Content = "You need to turn on a button called 'Get to know me'...",
        PrimaryButtonText = "Shut up",
        SecondaryButtonText = "Shut up and show me the setting"
    };
    if (await Dialog.ShowAsync() == ContentDialogResult.Secondary)
    {
        const string uriToLaunch = "ms-settings:privacy-speechtyping";
        //"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42391526/exception-the-speech-privacy-policy-" + 
        //"was-not-accepted-prior-to-attempting-a-spee/43083877#43083877";
        var uri = new Uri(uriToLaunch);

        var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);

        if (!success) await new ContentDialog
        {
            Title = "Oops! Something went wrong...",
            Content = "The settings app could not be opened.",
            PrimaryButtonText = "Shut your mouth up!"
        }.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

[More ways to launch the Settings app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app)

Answer (score 0):

Open this setting in ShellExecute as url "ms-settings:privacy-speech".